# Application hosted on AWS to access multiple external DB's

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, data-warehouse, amazon-rds

This question is not purely related to application development, but quite from an architectural point of view. Let's say an application has to be hosted on AWS, which will require communication from multiple external 3rd party held databases (not mandatory to be on AWS, could be their own data center or a colocation) - maybe one client would be using MySQL, another one MSSQL, or Oracle etc.

So, the data held in these external databases could be changing frequently and all the time the application should retrieve the updated data. One way I could think of is to use another RDBMS DB (from our side) specifically to store all these data from external DB's and to keep our DB in sync all the time. But I am not sure if this is a good way to achieve this.

Or do I need to use any data warehousing tool like Redshift to store all the data synced in real time and then use DW data in our application? According to the architects here, what would be a good solution for achieving this, mainly with multiple external DB connectivity and syncing?

Comment: You could hook up a connection between your VPC and the remote data centers, you could also use the Direct Connect service for better connectivity.

Comment: It would be great if you can provide more information about your usecase to give a better answer. So what sort of a application you are referring to? Its also important to know, roughly how much of data you are having in those external databases. Do you need to sync all the data or partial? How soon you need to make new data available to other databases?

Comment: @Ashan: This could be a mobile application (android/ios) which would be used by public. I cant figure you an exact size of external DB. Since there would be multiple locations/client DB's from where I need to retrieve data, I assume atleast a TB data would be there. So, I am okay if there's a solution without syncing the data - just my mobile application should talk to many DB's of many clients and get the required information real time. 

I hope this would give you a bigger picture.

Comment: @ShimonTolts: I am talking from DB perspective and not network or connection related.

Comment: So basically you need to build a mobile application, which requires to retrieve data from different databases located from different datacenters both for read and write? Do you also have webservers on those datacenters?

Comment: @Ashan: Some clients has. and some doesnt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your usecase, I would recommend to create an REST API which will work as the backend service for Mobile App.

There are few reasons, you shouldn't use your mobile app to directly connect to backend databases.

Security Risk

- Requires to make Databases publicly accessible which is a high security risk.
- Another security risk is there in storing Database access credentials inside Mobile App.

Performance

- Directly communicating with the Database can cause performance issues with respect to data transfer where if you have a backend service, which could optimally send and receive batches of data after combining from different sources based on queries.
- Also can get the benefit of server side caching by having an API or a backend service.

By having a Universal View of Your Data through your API, you can connect to multiple databases and retrieve data accordingly, also handling authentication and authorization within your API.

Following diagram illustrates an architecture using Serverless technology stack(API Gateway & Lambda) in AWS to build an API which could connect to multiple backend databases.

[image: Serverless Architecture Solution]

Few points to highlight

- You can decide on having a single Lambda or Multiple Lambda functions based on the complexity of your business logic.
- Recommend to place all the Lambda's in a VPC and then have a VPN connection to your remote data centers so that the database access don't need to be exposed publicly.

Comment: Thats awesome.. But you mean:

1. to create API's for different databases and when a request comes in to a specific point, redirect to there..
OR
2. to create a single API that will communicate with multiple DB layer. If this is the case how am I supposed to store multiple connection strings and credentials and how to access it.?

Comment: I'm referring to the option 2 to create a single API and communicate with multiple databases. You have multiple options to store database keys. Most secure way would be to store them in AWS KMS and allow access to them from Lambda. Or else you can keep them in Lambda environmental variables. 
Apart from the above proposed solution, you also can setup a Web Server to do this (But I would recommend to go with Serverless because of the cost savings and speed of development)

Answer (score 2):

Starting from there:

> So basically you need to build a mobile application, which requires to
>   retrieve data from different databases located from different
>   datacenters both for read and write

The cheapest way is to allow the app connect directly to those DBs so you don't need extra infrastructure at all. Disadvantages: security (you have to store DB credentials on the mob. client) and impossibility to implement centralized cache.

Option 2: modify your app to use an intermediary which is located at AWS and in its turn connects to cache and the original DBs. Perhaps API Gateway may come in handy. If you need the intermediary to be really fast I suggest to use not lambda but ec2 with auto-scaling. Requires some money and time.

Option 2.5: in addition to option 2 you can add DB slaves to your AWS account as read replicas. Faster but more expensive.

Option 3: move the DBs to AWS and leave read replicas on the old location. May be impossible from business point of view.

Option 4: set up master-master replication between original DB and DB on ec2 (RDS does not allow master-master afaik). Disadvantage: I'm unsure about stability.

Don't forget to encrypt your DB traffic in transit, it is not secured with SSL by default.